# Use facebook login as authentication for mobile apps.

Tags: php, android, ios, jwt, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 to make an rest API for mobile apps. For authentication in the mobile apps they should only use Facebook login. So my question is how can i implement this rest api with facebook authentication.

I was thinking to make a users model at the server side and when a user logins with facebook from the app I get all the information for the user and save it in the users model, like name email photo ect. If the user is already registered in my users model I was thinking to get the users email address from facebook and compare it to users in my users model to get the users info.

According to accesstoken I was thinking to use JWT, but I'm not sure how? My solution could maybe be when a user login with facebook my api either save the user or get the user and then return and JWT token. Hope you guys understand my problem and can help me out - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think facebook login should be implemented on front end , there are simple ios / android sdks for facebook login and on login user gets the info as requested in facebook developer account and then using a simply api that info can be stored at your server side , just create a user id for that user to identify uniquely

Comment: Yes, fb login will be on front-end. When I use fb login I'll get the needed information and save the data in my users model. Let say my users has one to many relationship with a model called books. How will I get all books for a current user? Should I also save fb accesstoken and use that token to get all books for a user or should I generate own accesstoken?

Comment: No you don't need access token , after you store the info , attach an user id and all the request for that user info will be made through user id

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/, it is really simple. The link contains step by step how to achieve the login. With google identity toolkit it easy to add other ways to login, like Gmail, Yahoo, etc.

But if you need only Facebook, you could start here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started?locale=es_LA